# Read multiple csv datasets with the date text from file name as new column

Tags: r, csv, readr

I have multiple csv files that I want to import into R.

How do I read multiple files into R and add a column with the date text from the file name in the first column?

Need here:

For each csv file take the date found in the file name and add it as the first column of each dataframe before rbinding them.

[image]

Here is the code without the date column from the file name:

```
all <- lapply(c("file_10-16-2017.csv",
                "file_10-17-2017.csv",
                "file_10-18-2017.csv",
               function(x){
               read_csv(x, skip = 10)}) %>% bind_rows()
```

I want my final result to look something like this:

```
Date_Pulled      Week         Date      spot1      Site ID test 
 10-16-2017  10/15/17   10/16/2017      trial          trial134
     .           .           .             .              .
     .           .           .             .              .
     .           .           .             .              .
 10-17-2017  10/15/17   10/16/2017      trial          trial134
     .           .           .             .              .
     .           .           .             .              .
     .           .           .             .              .
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to come up with another method:

```
filenames <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE, full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE, ignore.case = FALSE)

read_csv_filename <- function(filenames){
  ret <- read.csv(filenames, skip = 10)
  ret$Source <- filenames #EDIT
  ret
}

import.list <- ldply(filenames, read_csv_filename)
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

First, put all of the files you want to read into a separate working directory, and change the working directory to this one.

```
# 1. change wd
setwd('new_file_path')

# 2. get files from that directory
my_files <- list.files()

# 3. read in all files, skipping first 10 lines
library(readr)
dat_list <- lapply(my_files, read_csv, skip = 10)

# 4. mutate a new column, which is the name of the file
library(dplyr)
dat_list_new <- lapply(dat_list, function(x) {
    mutate(x,
           new_col_one = names(x))
})

# 5. port this list of data frames to the global environment
names(dat_list_new) <- my_files # set the names of the dataframes
list2env(dat_list_new,envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. There was an error that said, "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: could not find function "name"." in step 4. Does that require a different package besides readr and dplyr?

Comment: Should be names()

Comment: Yes, should be `names()`. I wrote this in a hurry and didn't test it on data. This answer should get you more than halfway there.

Comment: Hi sorry, I got another error after this that says: " Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `new_col_one` must be length 13619 (the number of rows) or one, not 42" There are 42 columns in my dataset

Comment: You're right. I see that. It's because the number of files you're reading in is 42, so names(x) actually gives a vector of all names. You need the name of the list element under operation at that time. I'm actually not sure how to do that on the fly.